# Understanding wave function graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

[image: Graphical representation of wave function and its probability density]

I found this graph from the internet that interprets the graphical representation of wave function.I completely understand the wave function that is depicted by blue line but i really am confused about the probability density of wave function on the right side of the graph. Why the wave peak always directing towards the positive y axis? Why there is no component on the negative $y$ axis? Anybody please explain the physical phenomena of it.

Comment: It is a mathematical triviality: The absolute square $|\psi|^2$ of any number $\psi$ is always positive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$|\psi|^2 = \psi^* \psi$, with $^*$ the complex conjugate. You may remember from your complex number introduction that $|z|^2 = z z^*$ is always real and positive for any complex number $z$.

Answer (score 0):

The Probability density graph is never negative because there can be no negative probability. negative probability doesn't make any sense.

Comment: But when it extends to negative x axis what happens then

Comment: It doesn't happen for the $|\psi|^2$ graph, but only for the graph of the wave function, and it is ok, because that is not a probability.

Comment: okay i get it now.

Comment: @F.sharmin The negative x-axis is fine. That just means there's some (positive) probability of measuring a negative value of x.